# Python get how to detect Public DNS?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In Python (Django) I need a way to detect origin of a request, traditionally I have used Python to detect the client IP, however, in my production my Client server uses AWS with a load balancer so I need a way to detect the request is coming from a DNS like i.e.

Public DNS: `ec2-11-11-11-48.eu-north-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Is there a way to detect the public DNS of the server from the client i.e. for IP I do this:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip  

 class IpAuthentication(Authentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        return get_client_ip(request) in SETTINGS.ALLOWED_IPS:
```

**So what I'm asking is:** is there a way to make sure that my clients requests are coming from a particular AWS instance?

Comment: Have you evaluated possibility of buying a static IP on AWS? http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346

Comment: won't work I use a load balancer + other reasons I mean I do have an IP but it changes so cannot be used for validation. I'm sure there is a way to valid the client is on the same instance maybe using boto?

Comment: Cant really understand your architecture. I dont see a role of load balancer, if an EC2 instance is calling your django service.

Comment: Sorry, EC2  is calling the service. API and client on the same server. I want to validate the clients request are from the same ip/domain. setup.  client > load balancer > ec2 instances . but i need to make sure the client is making the call from one of the ec2 instances.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially want only another EC2 (which you started) to contact your server ?
Looks like it is better for you to use security groups. You need to create a security group and block all the access from outside in this. Then launch your server-EC2 and client-EC2 both using the same security group. This prevents all other access.

Read more here:
Amazon EC2 Security Groups - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html